# Is resume upload possible in browser?

Tags: actionscript-3, html

With the help of ActionScript or HTML5?

Comment: upload of just about anything is possible in browser with or without help of ActionScript or HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

In ActionScript you can use the data property of [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data) to set an arbitrary ByteArray to be uploaded. Your application could keep track of the number of bytes that were uploaded and then resume.

Of course the server that you you uploading to would have to support the ability to upload a file or data in multiple parts.

I am not aware of any generic mechanism to support resuming uploads. Maybe you can give an example of the situation you are trying to resume uploads in?

Comment: This has the disadvantage that everything needs to be loaded into memory, rather than only keeping small chunks in memory when needed (flash...)